# Calling super() to parent class using generics

Tags: java, generics

I have several classes that all extend the same `abstract class Encoder`. The abstract class requires its children to override an abstract method which accepts a generic-typed parameter (`Subscriber<T>` in this example). Each subclass overriding this method uses a different type for this parameter.

```
abstract class Encoder<T> {

  protected String mSomeArg;

  public Encoder(String someArg) {
    mSomeArg = someArg+" super";
  }

  public abstract void start(Subscriber<T> subscriber);
}


class ExampleEncoder extends Encoder {

  public ExampleEncoder(String arg) {
    super(arg); // how to make super class get generic type?
    // eg: new Encoder<Message>(arg)
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Subscriber<Message> subscriber) {
    Message msg = new Message("hi "+mSomeArg);
    subscriber.event(msg);
  }

}
```

Sample use case:

```
Encoder sample = new ExampleEncoder();
sample.start(new Subscriber<Message>() {
  @Override
  public void event(Message msg) {
    Log(msg.text());
  }
});

Encoder otherSample = new OtherEncoder();
sample.start(new Subscriber<OtherThing>() {
  @Override
  public void event(OtherThing thing) {
    Log(thing.toString());
  }
});
```

**Question:** How can each subclass call its `super()` with the generic type it requires for this abstract method?

*Note: Using `Subscriber<?>` in this abstract method for this example would defeat my purpose of using generics. Also, instantiating each subclass with the generic type it requires (eg: `new ExampleEncoder<Message>()`) seems like a plausible workaround, but also seems unnecessary*

Comment: Note that `class Encoder<EventType>` is super confusing (at least to me). Generics usually use only one letter to make it easy to spot. So that would be: `class Encoder<T>` for example.

Comment: Edited to make it simpler for the sake of posting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This

```
class ExampleEncoder extends Encoder {
```

is a [raw-type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). I'm fairly sure you wanted something like

```
class ExampleEncoder extends Encoder<Message> {
```

if you want the concrete class to also be generic then you could use

```
class ExampleEncoder<T> extends Encoder<T>
```

but you'd need to modify `start` to take a `Subscriber<T>`.